# Convert datetime c# to unixstamp in php

Tags: c#, php, datetime, time, unix-timestamp

I use API of service which return me c# DateTime string:
`/Date(1327914214000+0400)/`
And i should convert it to unixstamp, because i use php. So how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's `[strtotime][1]` function is perfect for this. It can handle most common date formats, including strings.

Another option is with MySQL functions FROM_UNIXTIME and UNIX_TIMESTAMP

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime_column) FROM table
```

This usually is faster than a PHP function call.

Answer (score 0):

For me the best solution came from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16749812/469995

`strtotime` has no effect and I don't even understand why it's a correct answer without preparing the parameter to send to `strtotime`